# Can you identify this tool?

Tags: tools

Does anyone know what these metal tools in the bottom left of the photo are? I found them in my crawlspace and to me they look like some sort of medieval torture device.

[image]

Comment: Try taking a better picture. Look like some sort of fireplace tools, but the picture is not good for sorting out details.

Comment: Is this house still under construction?  That crawlspace needs something on the floor - a layer of thick poly at very least.  Or is it a concrete basement that you filled with dirt for some reason?

Comment: @J... What's wrong with the dirt (just out of curiosity)?  My house has a crawlspace just like that with bare dirt.

Comment: @dalearn [Does Your Crawlspace Need a Vapor Barrier?](https://www.americover.com/blog/does-your-crawlspace-need-vapor-barrier/)

Comment: @dalearn [Does my Crawlspace Need a Vapor Barrier?](https://acculevel.com/crawl-space-need-vapor-barrier/)

Comment: @dalearn And code : `Crawl space encapsulation methods must include protection from ground water entry. Exposed earth in unvented crawl space foundations shall be covered with a continuous, minimum 6-mil polyethylene vapor retarder (2012 IRC Section R408.2) and it must be a Class I vapor retarder (IRC 2012 – N1102.1.10).   Vapor barriers should be secured to the ground floor, covering any exposed dirt. Joints must overlap no less than 6 inches, and all seams must be taped (Source: 2015 IRC - Section 408.3.1).`

Answer (score 42, accepted):

They are old ladder jacks.

Here is a picture in use:

[image: ladder jacks]

And they can go under as well:

[image: ladders jacks]